# Convert UTC Date to datetime string Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I have a UTC date string, "2011-10-30T18:30:00Z", and I want to convert it to "2011-10-30 18:30". Can anyone give me some advice how to do this? I would appreciate for your time and consideration.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
str=str.replace(/T|\:\d\dZ/g,' ')
```

Answer (score 22):

The easiest solution is to try the following:

```
var date = new Date("2011-10-30T18:30:00Z");
```

This will convert it into a normal Javascript date, at which point you can use whatever data operators you like.

Comment: In IE8 it returns NaN.
>>new Date("2011-10-30T18:30:00Z").toString()
"NaN"

Comment: Interesting. Does `new Date(Date.parse("2011-10-30T18:30:00Z")).toString()` work in IE8?

Comment: no, it returns "NaN" as well. Infact, it fails while doing Date.parse