# Convert UTC Date to datetime string Titanium

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile, datetime-format

I have a date string **"2012-11-14T06:57:36+0000"** that I want to convert to the following format **"Nov 14 2012 12:27"**. I have tried a lot of solutions including [Convert UTC Date to datetime string Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708223/convert-utc-date-to-datetime-string-javascript). But nothing could help me. The following code worked for me in android. But for ios it displays as **invalid date**

```
var date = "2012-11-14T06:57:36+0000";
//Calling the function
date = FormatDate(date);

//Function to format the date
function FormatDate(date)
{   
    var newDate = new Date(date);
    newDate = newDate.toString("MMMM");
    return (newDate.substring(4,21));   
}
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All browsers doesn't support the same date formats. The best approach we can choose is to split the string on the separator characters -, and : , and pass each of the resulting array items to the Date constructor, see the following function

```
function FormatDate(date)
{   
    var arr = date.split(/[- :T]/), // from your example var date = "2012-11-14T06:57:36+0000";
    date = new Date(arr[0], arr[1]-1, arr[2], arr[3], arr[4], 00);
    newDate = date.toString("MMMM");
    //.. do further stuff here  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a `Date` object by initializing a new date:

```
var date = "2012-11-14T06:57:36+0000";
var newDate = new Date(date); // this will parse the format

console.log(newDate);
> Wed Nov 14 2012 01:57:36 GMT-0500 (EST)
```

As for the formatting, there are several threads (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript)) on that already.

There are also libraries for date formatting and processing that people usually end up using when doing a lot of date processing. I would suggest [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) if you're looking for something like that.